# Automatically generated invaild URL

Tags: uri, redirection

In admin/config/search/redirect/404, I found a lot of invalid url, it's a lot of additional "products" on our url, for example, News/products/products/products/products/products/products;
LED-Replacement-Lamps/LED-RGB-Lights/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products;
[image: drupal]
The "NEWS" is our Contents, but "LED-Replacement-Lamps/LED-RGB-Lights/" is 301 redirect I do by "URL redirects”. So I want to know it's the problem of "URL redirect" tool or others?

I have check the patterns,but i did not find the issue.
I want to know why there is many links with additional "product" repeat again and again?
[image: pattern]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your  `pathauto` Patterns, go to `admin/config/search/path/patterns1` and check your pattern, it seems you have a pattern that when each time  the content edited Url  added to your `Url Alias` again.

I guess something like this exists there

```
 products/[node:url]
```

Comment: I have checked the patterns ,but I did not find this .And I have post the screenshot at the question.

Comment: @Eric what is the content type of the url mentioned in the  question ?

Comment: Thank you ,but what do you mean about content type of the url?

Comment: Do you mean "text/html"?

Comment: @Eric not content type ,I mean is this url `LED-Replacement-Lamps/LED-RGB-Lights/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products` of node with products content type?

Comment: This link is an old link and I have do a 301 redirect to my new link,http://www.eneltec-led.com/products/led-spot-lights,this page says"Content: Type (= Products)"

Comment: @Eric why you use redirect? if pathauto work correctly  and all products cotents  url be "products/[node:title]" why you use redirect?
please try this scenario I told, first disable all redirects, set pathauto pattern of products to "products/[node:title]" save and then create a new product node. and tell me what the url of it ( dont forget check url aliased checkbox)

Comment: Because our website have rebuild last year, and the links doesn't list in my site.

Comment: the new product URL is:products/test/

Comment: @Eric So it's ok. what is the problem?

Comment: Actually I want to know why there is many links with additional "product" repeat again and again?

Comment: @Eric there are several reasons that can cause this . your question was not clear and ... :(